# AWS template url for facebook

Tags: facebook, templates, url, amazon-web-services

I am trying to host my **facebook app** in **AWS**.
I tried to create stack as mentioned in the getting started guide  ->
[AWS Getting Started Guide](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Ruby/1044)

But I do not know what is the template url to be given for hosting facebook app.
Can anyone help me on  this?

Answer (score 0):

The template URL points to a [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) template. Templates are stored in S3 whenever you launch a stack which is why you're seeing a link pointing to S3 in the sample. From the documentation:

> AWS CloudFormation gives developers and systems administrators an easy way to create a collection of related AWS resources and provision them in an orderly and predictable fashion.

Basically, why configure things yourself if AWS has a template to do it for you? The link you provided states:

> This sample AWS CloudFormation template will launch all the necessary cloud resources you need to launch the sample app on AWS.

Is there any reason you can't use the sample CloudFormation template provided to get you up and running and configure it differently as needed?

Comment: I am looking for the sample template for facebook app. In the tutorial i am not able to find the full path of that template url.

Comment: The full path of the template URL is given to you when you click launch the stack from the tutorial. `http://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-facebook/SampleFacebookPHP.template`

Comment: Thanks a lot .Its there in the link as you have rightly pointed out